# React Native - ERROR point to the same directory in the file system. Each module must have a unique path

Tags: android, react-native

[image]

I try Sync Gradle in Android studio but i received error ERROR: The modules ['@react-native-community-geolocation-android-@react-native-community_geolocation', '@react-native-community-geolocation-android-react-native-community_geolocation~2'] point to the same directory in the file system. Each module must have a unique path. I check project in Android Studio, i see react-native-community_geolocation create multiple file .iml, 
what's cause and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Getting here a bit late but in case it will help someone. Heading to settings.gradle and removing this solve it for me :
include ':@react-native-community_geolocation'
project(':@react-native-community_geolocation').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/@react-native-community/geolocation/android')
React native 0.60 and up are using auto link so no need to manually link it.